# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Partial inside and outside the form with unobtrusive data validation attributes issue

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors, unobtrusive-validation

I have from with conditional content, according with conditions using jQuery i am including or excluding this parts from the form elements.

Here is my functions:

```
function MoveInsideForm(id) {
       $("#" + id).insertAfter("#myForm")
   }

function MoveOutsideForm() {
       $("#myPartial1").insertAfter("#element-outside-from");
       $("#myPartial2").insertAfter("##element-outside-from");
   }
```

The problem is with `insertAfter()` it is does not getting copied HTML 5 custom attributes

For example i have an element like that

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="*" id="MyInput" name="MyInput" type="text" value="" class="input-validation-error"/>
```

But `insertAfter()` copying it like that:

```
<input id="MyInput" name="MyInput" type="text" value=""/>
```

Is there any way i can say to `insertAfter()` to copy HTML 5 attributes as well?
My jQuery version is 1.6.1.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks guys for comments.
Here is the thing, when i am rendering my partials inside the form the inputs getting generated with unobtrusive data attributes, but if i am rendering my partials outside the form, the unobtrusive data attributes initially not getting included in to inputs.

So when i am rendered the partials outside the form they initially does not contain data attributes.
So it is not issue with jQuery `insertAfter()`, is it the nature of unobtrusive data validation attributes generation?

Comment: I prototyped some of your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/katsuke/sX67h/) and it seems to maintain the special attributes. Review my code and let me know if there is something I'm missing. (This was with JQuery 1.6)

Comment: @Katsuke To copy data attributes it is better to use method data() http://api.jquery.com/data/ but i am just wondering how to move everything including data attributes as well using insertAfter().

Comment: Vasya. i just tested the code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/geertvdc/mVXSQ/ and it does copy every attribute including the custom attributes (i'm testing in IE9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to generate unobtrusive validation, MVC must have a `FormContext`.  When you place an HtmlHelper outside of `Html.BeginForm` or `Ajax.BeginForm`, the HtmlHelpers will not have unobtrusive validation attributes, unless you manually instantiate a FormContext.  You can manually instantiate a FormContext by inserting the following code before your helpers:

```
this.ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
```

If you are placing your helpers before a BeginForm(), then be sure to clear the FormContext after your helpers and before beginning the form.

Comment: I'm loading form fields dynamically via a PartialView. Is there any negative side effects using the code above in the partial view?

Comment: @Nick Olsen, no there is no negative effects, provided you first test to see if the `FormContext` exists, e.g., `if (this.ViewContext.FormContext == null) {...}`.

Comment: @counsellorben: Good answer... I went mad today with this issue.